# "names do not match previous names" & "length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent" in r

Tags: r

[image]I'm beginner
so I have a big problem.T.T

let me show you my script

```
test_call = read_excel(path="E:\\matrix.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1", col_names=TRUE)
df <-  data.frame(test_call)
df2 <-as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))
n <- nrow(df2)
m <- ncol(df2)
rownames(A) <- 1:n
colnames(A) <- 1:m
B <- rbind(cbind(matrix(0,n,n),df2),cbind(t(df2),matrix(0,m,m)))
```

First question is when I ran "n <- nrow(df2)& m <- ncol(df2)" 
I got the warning message like "length of 'dimnames' [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhQ6G.png) not equal to array extent" 
I think I count the number of row and put those values into my row&column's name
I don't know why. 
Second question is I got the message  "length of 'dimnames' [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhQ6G.png) not equal to array extent" when i run "B <- rbind(cbind(matrix(0,n,n),df2),cbind(t(df2),matrix(0,m,m)))"
How can i solve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what are you trying to do there, without seeing what is your data and what is your endgame.

What is matrix A?

But is it possible that something like this would work for you?

```
test_call = read_excel(path="E:\\matrix.xlsx",
                       sheet="Sheet1", 
                       col_names=TRUE)
df <-  data.frame(test_call)
df2 <-as.matrix(table(df))
n <- nrow(df2)
m <- ncol(df2)
rownames(df2) <- 1:n
colnames(df2) <- 1:m
B <- rbind(cbind(matrix(0,n,n),df2),cbind(t(df2),matrix(0,m,m)))
```

Depending on how you want to call your columns, you can also do something like:

```
rownames(df2) <- NULL
colnames(df2) <- NULL
B <- rbind(cbind(matrix(0,n,n),df2),cbind(t(df2),matrix(0,m,m)))
colnames(B) <- 1:(n+m)
rownames(B) <- 1:(n+m)
```

Comment: you are really great. I made a mistake. You are right.
But when i use "B <- rbind(cbind(matrix(0,n,n),df2),cbind(t(df2),matrix(0,m,m)))" I got the message like "names do not match previous names"

Comment: Can you maybe share the data? Or sample of your data? You can use dput function in r to easily share what the data.frame(test_call) looks like.

Comment: how can i send my data to you??

Comment: in R, use: dput(data.frame(test_call))

Comment: it's very long output.T.T

Comment: in R, use: 

    dput(data.frame(test_call))

and paste the output at the top of your original question.

Comment: Share first few rows maybe?

Comment: I have edited the original answer to suggest a solution to your problem.

Comment: Oh really thanks~ but I got the same problem.
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
and I had my data's picture taken

Comment: even when you use `as.matrix(table(df))` instead of `as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))`

Comment: OH really sorry. My carelessness wear you out.
I have a question that what's different between as.matrix(table(df)) and as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))??
You are great guy Thanks~~

Comment: `as.data.frame.matrix` does not create a matrix. Try running `class(df2)` after using `as.data.frame.matrix` to create a df2. compare that to a class of an object created by `as.matrix`